# I can not access my files and other data which is in Ubuntu installation drive

Tags: partitioning

I am using Windows7 and before few days ago I was installed Ubuntu. My hard drive have 3 partitions. In one part Windows7 installed and in another part Ubuntu was installed.

Now my problem is that I can not access data which is available on the Ubuntu partition.

How can I access that data?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot access the data on your Ubuntu partition because windows does not know how to read ext3/ext4 partitions. To teach it how please read [this article](http://www.ubuntugeek.com/how-to-read-ext3ext4-linux-partition-from-windows-7.html).